# a certain number of random display elements

Tags: slice, shuffle

How to assign a random display of items on a permanent basis. For example, out of 200 elements, I want only 3 elements to be displayed in random order, but when clearing the cache files, it returns to its original position. Look at my code

```
if (!function_exists('get_latest_products')) {
function get_latest_products($limit)
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $key = "latest_products";
    if ($ci->default_location_id != 0) {
        $key = "latest_products_location_" . $ci->default_location_id;
    }
    $latest_products = get_cached_data($key);
    if (empty($latest_products)) {
        $latest_products = $ci->product_model->get_products_limited($limit);
        set_cache_data($key, $latest_products);
    } else {
        shuffle($latest_products);
        $latest_products = array_slice($latest_products, 0, 3, TRUE);
    }
    return $latest_products;
}
```

}

Comment: Please add a language tag of your code

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. just had to delete the value "else"